# Blackberry MapView not working on Device, while working on Simulator

Tags: blackberry, maps, android-mapview

I'm working on a BlackBerry application that uses a MapView.
At the moment, I'm only showing the MapView, nothing more.
This is a snippet from the code I use for it:

```
public class MapScreen extends MainScreen {
  private MapField map;

  public MapScreen() {
    super(MainScreen.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);

    map = new MapField();
    map.moveTo(new Coordinates(50.847573,4.713135, 0));
    add(map);

    //...
  }

  //...
}
```

I'm using `net.rim.device.api.lbs.MapField` because I have to be compatible with OS 5.0

On the simulator, everything's fine and it's working.
But the moment I deploy it on the device, I see a white screen...

The device has an internet connection, but only over Wi-Fi. First I was thinking that that was the problem, but according to ["Blackberry services that are available over Wi-Fi connections"](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/7335/BB_services_with_WiFi_connections_601699_11.jsp), it shouldn't be a problem.

So, does anybody know why it's not working on the device, and how I can solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say "the device has an internet connection, but only over Wi-Fi" which makes me beleive you don't have the real device provisioned with a BlackBerry data plan. You need that plan in order to access any BlackBerry services, even over Wi-Fi.

To check for an appropriate connection you can use:

```
if (CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_BIS_B) {
   // Connection will support BlackBerry services
} else if (CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) {
   // Connection will support BlackBerry services if BES allows the connection to BIS servers.
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm running it on a device without a sim-card. So if the user has a data plan without BlackBerry service, there's no possibility to use MapView?
And is there a possibility that I can detect that it isn't available, so I can show a message?

Comment: A user without a BlackBerry data plan will not be able to use BlackBerry maps. They may be able to use Google maps depending on the service they do have. Detection code edited into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A better way of checking for this is to check the ServiceBook entries for LBSConfig or variants thereof.

That allows devices that are no longer on a plan, but were once configured by one with LBS, to function properly.

```
private static final boolean have_lbs() {
    ServiceBook sb = ServiceBook.getSB();
    ServiceRecord[] records = sb.getRecords();
    int count = records.length;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < count; ++ii) {
        if (records[ii].getCid().toUpperCase().startsWith("LBS"))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```